# How can I get the raw download size of a request using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, request, puppeteer

That is, the total amount of data downloaded across all resources (including video/media), similar to that returned by Chrome DevTools' Network tab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way to do this as of January 2018 that works with all resource types (listening for the `response` event [fails for videos](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1274)), and that correctly counts compressed resources.

The best workaround seems to be to listen for the `Network.dataReceived` event, and process the event manually:

```
const resources = {};
page._client.on('Network.dataReceived', (event) => {
  const request = page._networkManager._requestIdToRequest.get(
    event.requestId
  );
  if (request && request.url().startsWith('data:')) {
    return;
  }
  const url = request.url();
  // encodedDataLength is supposed to be the amount of data received
  // over the wire, but it's often 0, so just use dataLength for consistency.
  // https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-dataReceived
  // const length = event.encodedDataLength > 0 ?
  //     event.encodedDataLength : event.dataLength;
  const length = event.dataLength;
  if (url in resources) {
    resources[url] += length;
  } else {
    resources[url] = length;
  }
});

// page.goto(...), etc.

// totalCompressedBytes is unavailable; see comment above
const totalUncompressedBytes = Object.values(resources).reduce((a, n) => a + n, 0);
```

Comment: doesn't work anymore: TypeError: Cannot read property '_requestIdToRequest' of undefined

Answer (score 4):

The solution of [@mjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263345/how-can-i-get-the-raw-download-size-of-a-request-using-puppeteer#answer-48263346) works perfectly even in 2021. Just need to replace:

page._networkManager -> page.**_frameManager**._networkManager

Full example that works for me:

```
const resources = {};
page._client.on('Network.dataReceived', (event) => {
  const request = page._frameManager._networkManager._requestIdToRequest.get(
    event.requestId
  );
  if (request && request.url().startsWith('data:')) {
    return;
  }
  const url = request.url();
  const length = event.dataLength;
  if (url in resources) {
    resources[url] += length;
  } else {
    resources[url] = length;
  }
});

await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263345/how-can-i-get-the-raw-download-size-of-a-request-using-puppeteer');

const totalUncompressedBytes = Object.values(resources).reduce((a, n) => a + n, 0);
console.log(totalUncompressedBytes);
```

Comment: this does not work with puppeteer v20. _frameManager does not exist on page anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using puppeteer, you have server side node... Why not pipe the request through a stream, or streams and then calculate the content size?

Also there is https://github.com/watson/request-stats

Also you may want to call page.waitForNavigation as you may be wrestling with async timing issues

Answer (score -1):

```
const imgaes_width = await page.$$eval('img', anchors => [].map.call(anchors, img => img.width));
const imgaes_height = await page.$$eval('img', anchors => [].map.call(anchors, img => img.height));
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks