# How can I know the size of a pdf file in pupeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, size

How can I know the size of a pdf file in pupeteer? in the documentation I can't find anything related, the closest thing is format, but I want to get the file size not the file format, any idea? thanks in advance
Searching the documentation for examples, I can only find references to format and width and length.

Comment: It's possible that it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/48263346/8353201